# RPM scriptlets fail when launched through mono 5.4 on redhat 6

Tags: c#, linux, mono, redhat, rpm

I have mono 5.4 installed on RedHat 6 using the procedure from here:

http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin-centos

I created a very simple rpm with a prein scriptlet using fpm:

https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm

prein.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

echo boo
```

something.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

echo do something
```

make_rpm.sh

```
fpm -s dir -t rpm -v 1.0 -n test --before-install prein.sh ./something.sh=/usr/bin/something.sh
```

If i install the resulting rpm by doing:

```
sudo rpm -i test-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

It works fine. However, if I try do the same through mono, the installation fails due to a crash in the prein scriptlet.

test.cs

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Test
{
   class Test
   {
      static void Main(string [] args)
      {
         Process p = new Process();

         p.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/rpm";
         p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i test-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm";
         p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
         p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

         p.Start();

         p.WaitForExit();
      }
   }
}
```

That is compiled doing:

```
csc test.cs
```

and run using:

```
sudo mono test.exe
```

I get:

```
error: %pre(test-1.0-1.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 127
error: install: %pre scriptlet failed (2), skipping test-1.0-1
```

The same procedure also has the same behavior on CentOS 6. However, it works as expected on Redhat 7. This also worked fine on RedHat/CentOS6 with previous versions of mono (specifically 4.0.2). Anyone have an idea why this is happening and how it might be fixed?

Comment: `exit status 127` : cmd not found.  Missing a path? No shell environment? etc....

Answer (score 0):

Well - ultimately I don't know what the problem was, but it went away when I built 5.4 from source. Even 4.2.4 from EPEL was exhibiting the issue.